# Vertical Alignment not working CSS HTML

Tags: html, css, web

I have been looking for tutorials how to center text in link.
Nothing helped. Could you help me out?
HTML:

```
<nav>

        <a class="but1" href="#"><strong>ART</strong></a>
        <a class="but2" href="#"><strong>VIDEOS</strong></a>
        <a class="but3" href="#"><strong>ABOUT</strong></a>
        <a class="but4" href="#"><strong>CONTACT</strong></a>

</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav a {
    font-size: 500%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    Height: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
    left: 50%;
    }

.but1 {
    background-color: #e24e42;
    top: 25%;
    }


.but2 {
    background-color: #e9b000;
    top: 50%;
}

.but3 {
    background-color: #eb6e80;
    top: 75%;
}

.but4 {
    background-color: #008f95;
    top: 100%;
}
```

I am starter in Web development. To be exact 2 days. If there are HUGE Mistakes, don't judge me.

Comment: Have you tried searching google? There are a ton of sites with tutorials on vertically centering content, including many links to stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers

Comment: I did google it and nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

Vertical alignment in CSS was a nightmare just a few years ago.

To try something like `vertical-align: middle;` means that you didn't even bothered to google it at all.

I woke up from that nightmare the moment I found flexbox. Take a look at this super complete guide on how to flexbox.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I think it's appropriated to create navigation menus, I use flexbox every time for that purpose.

EDIT:

I have been there and I know how hard small things can get in the beginning. Keep in mind that if you want to get serious in web design this will happen a lot and you must know how to deal with it alone.

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZTz7Q/2651/

You will notice that we only apply css flexbox properties on the parent element, defining how the children should be displayed:

`align-items: center` This is responsible for vertically center your content on the main axis (horizontal by default).

`justify-content: flex-start` This will align your content on the main axis, pretty much like `text-align:left`

Take some time to understand the code instead of copy and pasting it. It will help you to improve.

Comment: In code I did use it. It doesn't work. And I googled this problem for 2h+.